# ActiveRecord associations for existing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm converting a PHP app over to Rails and using an existing db. I'm new to Rails and having a hard time coming up with the correct associations (and naming conventions) for the following models:

```
baseball_players (one record per player)
    id, first_name, last_name, etc
baseball_stats (multiple records per player)
    player_id, year, position_id
baseball_positions (unique position names and id: a lookup table)
    id, position_name
baseball_players_positions (multiple player positions per player)
    player_id, year, position_id
```

I'm able to easily associate the players and stats models, but I'm having no luck joining them all together.

Any tips or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tables are exactly in the Rails pattern, you just have a prefix on them. If you are able to you could remove the prefix, or, if you aren't you have two options for implementing. One is [configuring the active record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) to add a prefix into all your model tables. The other way is to set the table prefix for each model through the [table_name](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name) method.

To configure the active record you can put the following code in the `applicarion.rb` file:

```
config.active_record.table_name_prefix = 'baseball_'
```

Comment: Thanks Pedro. I didn't know I could configure ActiveRecord to add the prefix. I'll give it a shot tomorrow, but I have a feeling that was my issue.